# mysqlimport vs Loading the SQL Format Dump

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Isn't mysqlimport rumoured to be **much faster** than loading the SQL format dump?

---

We have a database with nearly 60 million entries on the Windows platform, running `MariaDB 10.1.21`.  We created the tab delimited dump of the database, which was subsequently uploaded to a remote Linux system running `MySQL 5.6.49`.  It took 16 hours for the `mysqlimport` operation to complete.

Subsequently my colleague generated the SQL format dump, uploaded it to the same system and loaded it on the same system (using `mysql`).  This operation took about 17.5 hours to complete.

---

`mysqlimport` certainly took less time but didn't quite proceed at the blazing speed (relatively speaking) that we were expecting.  Is there any study that has been done comparing the time taken by the mysqlimport operation versus loading the SQL format dump?